# Copy paste link should get redirected to home page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a webpage using servlets. I have a home page with a simple sign-up and sign-in form along with forgot a password. So when I try to reset my password, when I try to copy-paste the link from firefox to chrome browser the page is getting displayed. But I want the home page to be displayed. The first three lines of code are in my RegisterServlet.java file. The last line of code in my register.servlet file. Is it possible to do like have if else in the following code so that copy paste link from one browser to another browser displays the homepage

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action1 = request.getParameter("action");

    if("forgot-password".equals(action1)) {

        /* set the title for pole.jsp */

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Forgot_password.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 
    } else{

        /* set the title for results.jsp */
        request.setAttribute("title","title for results.jsp");
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
            "/Register.jsp").forward(request, response);  

    } else {

        /* set the title for results.jsp */
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Register.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    }
```

}

```
<a href="RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
```

Here only I have to change RegisterServlet instead of ForgotPasswordServlet. Do I need to add any fields to the tag so that I can differentiate what JSP page to be accessed?

Updated the working code.

Comment: You have to use local storage and session storage to handle this

Comment: Means? Please let me know how to.

Comment: Setting a name and a value on a link won't make it send a parameter. A link is not a form field. To make it send a parameter "action" with the value "forgot-password", the href should be `RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password`. And you should avoid spaces in there to make it easier.

Comment: Edited the code. Is the above code correct. Please check and tell me.

Comment: I tried printing the action. Its returning null value.

Comment: `<a href="RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>` Is this correct?

Comment: You can use `session.isNew()` to check if session is new. Then redirect your request to home page.

Comment: Where to check this? Where should i add the code?

Comment: Copy paste the url **/webaddress/RegisterServlet?action=forgot-password** is displaying empty page in other browser. But i want it to get redirected to main login page.